# Print HTML page in WinForms without using IE

Tags: .net, winforms, internet-explorer

Is there any way to print HTML page in WinForms without using IE? Some our customers have problems with IE8 at Windows XP and I want to implement printing without dependence on IE.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/geckofx).

Or here -> [image: sample]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://geckofx.googlecode.com/files/geckofx-screenshot.png))</sub>

Comment: But it looks like there are some problems with printing: http://geckofx.org/viewtopic.php?id=168

Comment: hm.. there are workaround when you come to the end of the thread... didn't find any other .net-projects like geckofx. anyway: what kind of problems are there with ie8? and why can't they use an older version of ie?

Answer (score 1):

Try converting to a PDF. I'm not sure of the quality of the library, but [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfizer/) looks like it'll do what you need.